# Migrating a large media library

Tags: media-library, migration

The customer has an existing Sitecore media library of roughly 18GB and wants to migrate this toa new sitecore site. However, because of the size, creating export packages or serializing items, creates problems.
Do you know of any other practical way, than just creating multible smaller export packages, to migrate such a large media library?

(Yes, DAM for Sitecore will be installed later on, but for now we need to migrate the data)

Comment: Have you thought about using http://www.razl.net/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a quite elegant solution proposed in the sitecore community.

Basically, what you have to do is that you need to attach your "**old**" master database to the "**new**" sitecore instance as another db, e.g. "**master2**" and then write a simple code to create items/copy the blobs over to the "**new**" sitecore master database.

There is a good POC/instruction article about it:
https://pageditor.wordpress.com/2015/10/28/automated-migration-of-content-items-from-sitecore-6-5-to-sitecore-8-1/

Please take the following into consideration:

1. **Disable indexing**, otherwise it will take ages to migrate all the stuff. Dont forget to re-enable and rebuild indexes after import is over.
2. **Disable events** while importing and do a republish after it is finished.

Answer (score 1):

I know it's old and already has an accepted answer, however, it's from 5 years ago, so it might be helpful for someone now.
I have another approach to dealing with huge packages, try to divide this big package into small ones. I've developed a module to do it, check it out:

https://github.com/alvaropmontenegro/sitecore-media-package-generator
https://alvaropmontenegro.com/2023/04/13/media-package-generator/